# Plotting Global variable Highcharts

Tags: javascript, php, highcharts

After many failed attempts, I thought I would let someone smarter than me correct me. 
I am creating a simple chart using highcharts. The data is retrieved once (php code below) using $.post method. In the console I see that it is properly formatted. Yet, I cannot get highcharts to display it. I have tried many different ways from a variety of posts but still nothing.

Everything works fine if I use $.getJSON and then create the chart. However, my end user will probably go back and forth many time to review the same data. I do not want to query every time. My idea was to place the data on a global variable then just using that data to generate the chart.

Here is my php:

```
<?php 
    require_once "../includes/config_rev.php";
    require_once "../includes/connect.php";
    global $db;

    $st = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM mdo");   
    $st->execute();


        $category = array();
        $category['name'] = 'mes';

        $series1 = array();
        $series1['name'] = 'Temporeros';

        $series2 = array();
        $series2['name'] = 'Planta';

        $series3 = array();
        $series3['name'] = 'Movilizacion';

    foreach ($st as $stmenuselection)
        {
            $category['data'][] = $stmenuselection['mes'];
            $series1['data'][] = $stmenuselection['Temporeros'];
            $series2['data'][] = $stmenuselection['Planta'];
            $series3['data'][] = $stmenuselection['Movilizacion'];  
        }

    $results = array();
        array_push($results,$category);
        array_push($results,$series1);
        array_push($results,$series2);
        array_push($results,$series3);

    $json = json_encode($results, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
    echo $json; 
    $db = null;  
?>
```

Here is the JS that creates the chart:

```
var mdo;

$(document).ready(function()    {
    $.post('_presu_MDO.php', function ( data ) {mdo = data}); 
});

function manodeobra() {
    var options = {
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'mdo',
            type: 'bar'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Presupuesto de Mano de Obra',
            x: -20 //center
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: '',
            x: -20
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: mdo[0]
        },
        yAxis: {
            min: 0,
            title: {
                text: 'Requests'
            },
            labels: {
                overflow: 'justify'
            }
        },
        tooltip: {
            formatter: function() {
                    return '<b>'+ this.series.name +'</b><br/>'+
                    this.x +': '+ this.y;
            }
        },
        legend: {
            layout: 'vertical',
            align: 'right',
            verticalAlign: 'top',
            x: -10,
            y: 100,
            borderWidth: 0
        },
        plotOptions: {
            bar: {
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true
                }
            }
        },
        series: []
    }

    options.xAxis.categories = mdo[0]['mes'];
    options.series[0] = mdo[1]['Temporeros'];
    options.series[1] = mdo[2]['Planta'];
    options.series[2] = mdo[3]['Movilizacion'];
    chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);


}
```

How can I get the function manodeobra() to draw the chart using mdo variable without having to again run a query?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: so what is the question?

Comment: The plot won't display the data, although it is properly formatted on the console.

Comment: try:  $series1['data'][] = (int)$stmenuselection['Temporeros'];....Cast to integer. The sql query returns strings. Cast you those strings to int, float or what you need to plot them. Write with feedback

Comment: In your `$.post` call, show us what data equals.  Are you sure jQuery figures out your post is returning json?  Without explicitly specifying a `dataType` it guesses and it may be treating it as a string.  Also, any errors on the javascript console?  Highcharts is very good about returning errors when you give it improper data.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to help me Mark. Here is the console response from the server: [{"name":"mes","data":["enero","febrero","marzo","abril","mayo","junio","julio","agosto","septiembre","octubre","noviembre","diciembre"]},{"name":"Temporeros","data":[22000000,17000000,18000000]},{"name":"Planta","data":[15000000,15000000,15000000,]},{"name":"Movilizacion","data":[2000000,2000000,2000000]}]

Comment: There is your problem. Your data cannot be a string like `{"name":"mes","data":["enero","febrero","marzo","abril","mayo","junio","julio",‌​"agosto","septiembre","octubre","noviembre","diciembre"]}`. That looks like a category list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see a number of potential problems:

1.)  When do you call the `manodeobra` function?  Since `$.post` is async you need to make sure you don't call it until after that completes.

2.) You state that ajax looks like this array of objects:

```
[
    {
        "name": "mes",
        "data": [
            "enero",
            "febrero",
            "marzo",
            "abril",
            "mayo",
            "junio",
            "julio",
            ‌​"agosto",
            "septiembre",
            "octubre",
            "noviembre",
            "diciembre"
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "Temporeros",
        "d‌​ata": [
            22000000,
            17000000,
            18000000
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "Planta",
        "data": [
            15000000,
            15000000,
            150‌​00000, <-- IE won't like this!               
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "Movilizacion",
        "data": [
            2000000,
            2000000,
            2000000
        ]
    }
]
```

The dangling comma in `Planta` is invalid for IE.

Also you have:

```
options.xAxis.categories = mdo[0]['mes'];
options.series[0] = mdo[1]['Temporeros'];
options.series[1] = mdo[2]['Planta'];
options.series[2] = mdo[3]['Movilizacion'];
```

These properties on each array item don't exist in your JSON.  Also, your series attribute in your options object is an empty array, so `.series[1]` and `.series[2]` is invalid.

I would suspect you need:

```
options.xAxis.categories = mdo[0]['data']
options.series.push(mdo[1]);
options.series.push(mdo[2]);
options.series.push(mdo[3]);
```

3.) Learn to inspect the javascript console for errors (in IE or chrome press F12).  All of these problems would be evident if you checked it for errors.

Comment: Thank you for the advise Mark. I call the $.post when the page is loaded using - $(document).ready(function() { $.post... The function manodeobra is called when a tab within a jquery accordion. 2) ooops... post-pasting the results, I deleted some of the entries to make it more consice. I missed that comma. Do you have any other ideas? I made the changes that you suggested on point 3 but the graph is still being rendered empty - title and axis just no data. I will try reading further as to how to specify datatype and javascript console (In firefox I do not get any errors within console)

Comment: IT WORKED THANKS Mark!!
The solution (as you suggested) had to do with specifying the data type. 

I had to change:
$.post('_presu_MDO.php', function ( data ) {mdo = data}); 

With: 
$.post('_presu_MDO.php', function ( data ) {mdo = data},"json"); 

Thank you again Mark.